# unable to understand scope of macro definition in function

Tags: c, macros

I have defined macro in a function.I have used this macro in main function which works fine.

So does **macro** have **global scope**?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f()
{
#define SQUARE no*no
}

void main()
{
    int no;
    printf("Enter no");
    scanf("%d",&no);
    printf("Square of no = %d",SQUARE);
}
```

Comment: In the wording of the C standard, macros don't have scope at all.

Comment: It's a basic fact about macros that they are just text replacement. And besides, it's obvious from trying it, so why waste everyone's time asking this?

Comment: @JimBalter I think that is the wrong way to look at it, undefined behavior can compile and seem to work but it does not mean it is correct. So just trying it does not really mean it is ok or it really does what you think it does.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour No, it's not the wrong way to look at it. This question has nothing to do with undefined behavior or whether something seems to work or is correct; it's a specific question of fact: do macros have global scope or don't they? As I said, the answer is *obvious* from trying it ... this isn't about behavioral corner cases. And I said two things, the first being about *the specification* of macros ... and I put that one first for good reason. Your response might be reasonable if I had omitted that and had just said that behavior is all that matters, but I didn't.

Comment: "Global scope"? There's no such thing as "global scope" in C language.

Comment: If you `#define` a macro in a function, `#undef` it at the end. Not officially a scoped macro, but close enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Unless the macro was already defined ... so, no, not scoped.

Comment: To deny that C has global variables (and therefore global scope) is obscurantist pedanticism. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable#C_and_C.2B.2B ... and it's clear what the OP means by the term here, which isn't "global" in that sense. Macros have a lexical scope that extends from the point where they are defined to the end of the compilation unit or to where they are #undefed.

Answer (score 3):

It may seem like they have <s>global scope</s> file scope(*which is what you mean when you say global scope*) but macros don't have scope since they are replaced during preprocessing before semantic analysis. If we go to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) it says the following in `6.2.1` *Scopes of identifiers*:

> [...]Macro names and macro parameters are not considered further here,
>   because prior to the semantic phase of program translation any
>   occurrences of macro names in the source file are replaced by the
>   preprocessing token sequences that constitute their macro definitions.

Comment: Note quite sure why someone would downvote this for.

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you from trying it yourself?

The answer is yes. It has **global scope**.

Comment: I tried.It works fine

Comment: Then there was no reason to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

In C language macros are processed at early phases of translation. At that stage the language-level notion of scope is not yet applicable. Macros are processed without regard to any scope.

Note that C language does not have such scope as "global scope". C language only defines *file* scope, *function* scope, *block* scope and *function prototype* scope. That's it. No "global" scope.

The section of language specification that deals with scopes (6.2.1) explicitly states

> Macro names and macro parameters are not considered further here,
>   because prior to the semantic phase of program translation any
>   occurrences of macro names in the source file are replaced by the
>   preprocessing token sequences that constitute their macro definitions.

which means that the notion of scope is not applied to macros.